# I would like to understand the meaning of applying permutation to a unitary matrix

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-state, programming, unitarity

$$U = \frac{1}{2}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\\\
  1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\\\
  1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\\\
  1 & -1 & 1 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$P = \frac{1}{2}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\\\
  1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\\\
  -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\\\
  1 & -1 & 1 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}$$

P matrix is a matrix obtained by swapping the 1st and 3rd columns of the U matrix.

Subsequently, I used Qiskit to apply U and P to a quantum circuit and observed the state vector.

```python
%matploblib inline
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.extensions import *
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

U = (1/*2) * np.array([
    [-1, -1, 1, 1],
    [1, -1, 1, -1],
    [1, -1, -1, 1],
    [1, -1, 1, 1]])
P = (1/*2) * np.array([
    [1, -1, -1, 1],
    [1, -1, 1, -1],
    [-1, -1, 1, 1],
    [1, -1, 1, 1]])

gate = UnitaryGate(U)

circuit = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
circuit.append(gate, [0, 1])

ket = Statevector(circuit)
ket.draw('latex')
```

This is the resulting state vector obtained by applying U and P, while varying the initial state.
[image]

As can be seen in the table above, the state vectors of U and P swap with each other when the initial vectors are |00> and |10>. However, I have realized that this is related to swapping the 1st and 3rd columns of U to create P, but I am not currently able to provide an accurate explanation for the reasons and interpretation of the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to review the definition of the matrix representation of an operator in a given basis:
If the matrix $U$ is the representation of some operator $u$ in the basis $\{|00\rangle,|01\rangle,|10\rangle,|11\rangle\}$, it means that the first column of $U$ contains the coordinates of $u(|00\rangle)$ in that basis, the second column is $u(|01\rangle)$ and so on:

$\begin{array}{cc}
    \begin{array}{cccc}\phantom{2} \text{$ \tiny   u(|00\rangle)$} & \text{$\tiny u(|01\rangle)$} & \text{$\tiny u(|10\rangle)$} & \text{$ \tiny u(|11\rangle)$} \\
   \end{array}
   &\\
\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
\phantom{2}-1\phantom{2} & \phantom{}-1\phantom{}& \phantom{2}1\phantom{2}&\phantom{2}1\phantom{2}\\
1 & -1 & 1& -1\\
1 & -1& -1&1\\
1 & -1 & 1& 1\\
\end{bmatrix}%
%
&\begin{array}{l}
          \left.\vphantom{\begin{bmatrix} 0\\
\end{bmatrix}}\right. \text{$\tiny |00\rangle$}\\ 
\left.\vphantom{\begin{bmatrix} 0\\
\end{bmatrix}}\right. \text{$\tiny |01\rangle$}\\ 
\left.\vphantom{\begin{bmatrix} 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}}\right. \text{$\tiny |10\rangle$}\\
        \left.\vphantom{\begin{bmatrix} 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}}\right. \text{$\tiny |11\rangle$}\\
        \end{array}   \\
\end{array}$

So if you swap the 1st and 3rd columns, you swap $u(|00\rangle)$ and $u(|10\rangle)$, the others are left untouched.

(I used your operator $U$ in my answer but you should be aware it is not unitary)

Comment: Ah, so is it correct to understand that swapping the 1st and 3rd columns simply means exchanging the positions of the basis? And U is likely to be unitary because in the Qiskit code 'gate = UnitaryGate(U),' an error would occur if U is not unitary! Thank you for your response.

Comment: You are not really changing the order of the basis of the 2-qubits state space: it is still
 $\{|00\rangle,|01\rangle,|10\rangle,|11\rangle\} $.

You exchange the result of the operator $U$ applied to $|00\rangle$ (the 1st vector in the basis) and the result of the operator $U$ applied to $|10\rangle$ (the 3rd vector in the basis).

I don't know what Qiskit should do but I confirm $U$ is not unitary; you can see that by taking the inner product of column 1 and 2 for example is is $-\frac{1}{2}$, it should be 0.

$U \text{ Unitary} \Leftrightarrow UU^*=U^*U=I$

Comment: Ah, it turns out the matrix is not unitary. I've confirmed it.